# Is it possible to make http application as a PWA?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I had made the changes for my website to adapt to progressive web app guidelines but since ServiceWorker is not available on HTTP domain I was not able to make my application work on offline mode. Can anyone suggest some solutions regarding the same using and certificate or other alternative measures to make HTTP application as a complete PWA app which works in offline mode too.

Comment: HTTPS is a core requirement. You need to use one.

Answer (score 4):

**Service Workers** have the ability to intercept every HTTP call from the site, and runs independently in the background. It sits between the browser and server. So, *it's a huge security risk if necessary restriction aren't put into it*. That is why Service Workers can only be used in **HTTPS** connections.

If your only need the catching mechanism, then you can use **[Cache API](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/cache-api)**. *Service Workers* themselves use the *Cache API* for making the site
available in offline.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can make a PWA using the HTTP protocol.

The only problem is that you can't download it to your computer, it only works from mobile devices (adding the site to the home screen, if the code is correct it will automatically install the PWA).
[Here](https://it.semrush.com/blog/cose-una-pwa-progressive-web-app/) you can see a good code to make PWA (it's in Italian but you can traslate).

Comment: Adding to home screen and installing are two very different things: the first one is just a shortcut/bookmark. The second one creates an APK on the fly and installs it.

Comment: also "Add to homesreen" with standalone/fullscreen manifest makes the ultimate difference, since no PWA on HTTP, no standalone view